# Some objects not showing in object mode

Tags: objects

I am a newbie in Blender 2.8. Some of my objects stopped to show up when I switch to "Object mode". What is going on? Thanks for a great forum.[image: Edit mode][image: Object mode]

Comment: Hello, this is not part of the question but you are definitely not showing screenshots from the 2.8+ versions.

Comment: Sorry. 2.79 :-)

Comment: You are using a boolean *Intersect* with another object. My best guess is that there actually is no intersection between these objects and the resulting geometry is empty. :) Try deactivating this modifier and see if the geometry appears

Comment: Not a bad guess at all! You solved it. Thanks a lot!!!